# check array of objects and compare its object values

Tags: javascript

I have a simple array of objects and I'd like to check if all the object in that array has the same value for a specific property.

```
const arr = [{
    name: "Test",
    value: 90
}, {
    name: "OP",
    value: 90
}, {
    name: "Test",
    value: 120
}]
```

Here I want to compare all the `value` property of every object element.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A `for` loop should already do the job.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @Andreas I have tried the some and every but couldn't figure out how the logic for comparing the property

Answer (score 0):

```
// get first objects value for comparison
let same_value = arr[0]['value'];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
  if (arr[i]['value'] != same_value) {
    return false;
  }
}
```